# how to redirect to instagram edit screen from android app

Tags: android, instagram

here i have question on instagram.

i am developing an android application which includes instagram sharing.

below is the code which i used to share the image through instagram.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");      
if(uriSharingImage==null){
        uriSharingImage=getImageUriFromBitmap(activityInstance,GridViewGalleryFragment.bitmapPreviewGallery);
}
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriSharingImage);
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

and its redirecting to 'instagram CROP' screen, but my requirement is redirect to "instagram EDIT" screen.

how can i achieve my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file of an app generally one activity handles proper action. For send action, you cannot pass crop section. You can be sure by decompiling instagram app and read its manifest and re-evulate your code

Comment: but its redirecting crop screen right. is it default intent?

Comment: Yes. Maybe they are going to pass it since they have started to allow non-square photos

Comment: ok.. Thanks for your answer.. if i use instagram sdk is my requirement has been achieved?

Comment: there is no instagram sdk for android? is there?